# In "Radiant", do all Sorcerers have "animal-like" features?

Tags: radiant

In the *Radiant* anime, episode  3; Don Bossman shows of his horns which seem more like bat wings.

[image: Don Bosman with his "bat wings" horns]

Seth is a Sorcerer that also has horns.

Does this mean all Sorcerers have "animal-like features"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it's only in some cases as mentioned in the 4th or 5th episode.

The girl named Melie is also a Sorcerer and she has a curse of personality change, and I don't think any animal has this feature.

Comment: Hmm good point so all sorceres have curses? which range from animal features to personality issues i guess?

Comment: Yep the curses can be anything which affects human body or mind.